# It is possible to round up integers using format?

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a large integer, ie: 123123123 and format it with 3-digits of precision and commas.  Format can add the commas using:

```
'{:,}'.format(123123123)  # '123,123,123'
```

And specify precision for floating points:

```
'{0:.2f}'.format(3.141592) # '3.14'
```

But what if I want to do both?

ie:

```
'{:,3d}'.format(123123123)  # ValueError
```

I would like to have it return: 123,000,000

Comment: The closest I can get is this: '{:,.0f}'.format(round(123123123,-6)) but it feels like format should be able to do this by itself.  :)

Comment: No, it's not possible to do this directly. The whole point of Python integers is that they're infinite-precision.

Comment: As a side note, it's simpler to just use the `format` function than to build a `{}` string to call the method on: `format(123123123, '.2f')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'right' way to do this that is Python version independent (well -- it has to have `with` so 2.5+) is use the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import decimal
import sys

if sys.version_info.major<3: 
    ic=long
else:
    ic=int    

def ri(i, places=6):
    with decimal.localcontext() as lct:
        lct.prec=places
        n=ic(decimal.Decimal(i,)+decimal.Decimal('0'))
    return format(n,',')

print(ri(2**99, 4)) 
# 633,800,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
print(ri(12349159111, 7))    
# 12,349,160,000
print(ri(12349111111, 3))  
# 12,300,000,000
```

If you use the [round method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826226/298607) it is fairly fragile on Python 2:

Python 2:

```
>>> format(round(12349999999999999,-6),',')
'1.235e+16'    # wrong....
```

It works on Python 3, but this is the way to do it so the rounding is left to right:

```
def rir(i, places=6):
    return format(round(i, places-len(str(i))), ',')

print(rir(2**99, 4))   
# 633,800,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
print(rir(12349159111, 7))   
# 12,349,160,000
```

With a negative offset for `ndigits`, [round(number[, ndigits])](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) will round the mantissa of the floating point right to left:

```
>>> round(123456789,-4)
123456789123460000
```

Works great on Python 3 with larger numbers:

```
>>> round(123456789123456789,-8)
123456789100000000
```

On Python 2, the functionality breaks with larger numbers:

```
>>> round(123456789,-4)
123460000.0
>>> round(123456789123456789,-4)
1.2345678912346e+17
```

With the decimal module, it works as expected on Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: If you need the equivalent of Python 3's `round` in Python 2, it's trivial to write it yourself. So, it _is_ a problem that many people don't realize they have to do so—but all you have to do is point out that they have to write it, and they'll have no trouble doing so.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this directly. The whole point of Python integers is that they're infinite-precision; if you want to round them, you have to do it explicitly. In fact, when you attempted the obvious, the message in the exception told you this:

```
>>> '{:,.3d}'.format(123123123)
ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier
```

So, your attempt at this is in the right directly… but it's more than a little funky:

```
'{:,.0f}'.format(round(123123123,-6))
```

There's no reason to explicitly force the `int` to a `float` just so you can print it without any fractional values. Just let it stay an `int`:

```
'{:,}'.format(round(123123123, -6))
```

Besides being simpler, this also means that when you try to one day print a giant integer, it won't give you an `OverflowError` or lose more digits than you wanted…

In earlier versions of Python (that is, 2.x), where `round` always returns `float` no matter what type you give it, you can't do that; you will probably want to write a trivial `intround` function instead. For example:

```
def intround(number, ndigits):
    return (number + 5 * 10**(-ndigits-1)) // 10**-ndigits * 10**-ndigits
```

If you know for a fact that you will never have an integer too large to fit losslessly into a `float`, you can just use `int(round(*args))` instead—but really, if you can avoid converting integers to floats, you should.

And, while we're at it, there's no reason to build up a `{}` string to call the `format` method on when you can just call the free function:

```
format(round(123123123, -6), ',')
```

Comment: I don't think the decimal point is wanted here. `format(round(123123123, -6), ',.0f')` is probably better for the last example

Comment: @gnibbler: There _is_ no decimal point here. The value is an `int`.

Comment: @gnibbler: ["The return value is an integer if called with one argument, otherwise of the same type as number."](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

Comment: @gnibbler:  this is a Python 2 vs Python 3 thing.  You're right about Python 2.

Comment: `format(round(123123123,-6),',')` give `123,000,000` in Python 3 but `123,000,000.0` in Python 2

Comment: @TimPeters: Which is why my answer explicitly tells you what to do with older versions of Python.

Comment: @furas: Please read the above comments, and the paragraph in the answer beginning "In earlier versions of Python, where `round` always returns `float`…"

Comment: @abarnert, I knew that, but "earlier versions" doesn't mean much when  you don't identify the version you think of as being the "not earlier" version :-)

Comment: @TimPeters: Surely there's a reason Python comes with docs, and an interactive interpreter, and built-in help, and so on. Anyone who's too lazy or too clueless to figure out what his particular version does is generally not going to read the answer anyway, he's just going to copy and paste some code and then say "it doesn't work". But if you insist, I'll edit the answer to make it clear.

Comment: @abarnert, no, I don't insist. Just noting that it would have taken a lot less bother just to type "Python 3" when you had "Python 3" in mind all along ;-)

Comment: @abarnert it was to `And, while we're at it, there's no reason to build up a {} string to call the format method on when you can just call the free function: format(round(123123123,-6),',')`. OP didn't say what version he use - so `format(round(123123123,-6),',')` can give not what OP expected. Only `'{:,.0f}'.format(round(123123123,-6))` give `123,000,000` in both version.

Comment: @furas: Well, if you just read one paragraph at random and ignore the rest of the answer and assume that any code that appears anywhere must be exactly what you want, you're often going to be disappointed. Presumably the OP doesn't have that problem. Whether he's using Python 3, or he read the paragraph that explains what to do if he's not and dealt with it, either way he wins.

Comment: @TimPeters: You're right; sometimes I bend over backward a little too far in trying to combat the impression many people on this site give that 2.7 is the "current" version of Python and 3.3 is some wacky experimental development version that isn't worth looking at and can't run any modules anyone cares about…

Comment: @abarnert: It sounds like you have a chip on your shoulder and might be trying to punish people -- when in fact you're probably just adding to the confusion.

Comment: @martineau: How is it "punishing" anyone to call 2.x an older version of Python?

Comment: @drewk: It's only converting to float that breaks on larger numbers. Which is exactly why the answer says you should avoid doing that. And it even explains that: "Besides being simpler, this also means that when you try to one day print a giant integer, it won't give you an OverflowError or lose more digits than you wanted…"

Comment: The `intround` formula `n // 10**-d * 10**-d` is wrong. Compare `round(12999, -3)` with `n=123999; d=-3; n // 10**-d * 10**-d` round produces 13000.0 and the formula produces 12000. It is a simple truncation.

Comment: @drewk: Good point. You obvious need to write a _correct_ `intround` function. I'll edit the answer.